# Count the number of Array in mongoDB without null

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document like that:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55fa4615b70ad91c40069736"),
    "test": [
        null,
        true
    ]
}
```

The `"test"` field is array with 2 elements. I want to count the number of array without `null` value use aggregate. I do like that:

```
{$project: { count: { $size: '$test' } }}.
```

But it return to 2. I want to it return to 1 (don't count the `null` value)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[setIntersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)** to filter out `null` in project to find out array size. Check following query :

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$project":{"testSize":{"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$test",[null]]}}}})
```

new edit:

use `aggregation` as below :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$test"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "test": {
      "$ne": null
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "test": {
      "$push": "$test"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "testSize": {
      "$size": "$test"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your solution is not solve my problem. If I have array like that:{
    "_id": ObjectId("55fa4615b70ad91c40069736"),
    "test": [
        null, 
        true, 
        null
    ]
}

it should return the count is 1. (ignore 2 value with the null)

Comment: as per your question you don't count the null value. so above query return only one size

Comment: { "_id": ObjectId("55fa4615b70ad91c40069736"), "test": [ null, true, null, true ] }. How about this case. It should return 2 value with the 'true' if I setIntersection is true.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Your answer is true. Have you any way to do without using $unwind?

Comment: @KennyTrinh I will check with other options I know `unwind` creates slow query :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    db.collection.aggregate({"$unwind": "$test"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "test": {
      "$ne": null
    }
  }
},
 {$group:
{_id:"size",
  size:{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{_id:0,size:1}})
```